# ChartJS executes a function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS to draw a line chart. The problem is that I'm trying to draw some small lines on Vertical axis to mark the axis in each 10% like this:

```js
extendChartLine: function() {
    window.Chart.plugins.register({
          beforeDraw: function(chart) {
            var ctx = chart.chart.ctx,
              chartArea = chart.chartArea,
              spacing = (chartArea.bottom - 40) /10;

            for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
              ctx.restore();
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(40, chartArea.bottom - i*spacing);
              ctx.strokeStyle = '#333';
              ctx.lineTo(47, chartArea.bottom - i*spacing);
              ctx.lineWidth = 0.2;
              ctx.stroke();
              ctx.closePath();
              ctx.save();
            }
          }
     });
```

The problem is that is function is called many times causing those lines are drawing more than one time and collapsing on each others (I know that because some lines are darker than others)
I tried to use a flag variable in order to make use these codes are executing on 1 time only, but no lines are drawing on the chart.

Comment: why can't you try creating multi lines chart with multiple dataset like one provided in this codepen: https://codepen.io/k3no/pen/pbYGVa

Comment: You have a for loop that executes many times. Why don't you change it for something else?

Comment: That's not multiple lines chart. I'm trying to draw small lines on the vertical axis which device each 10% of the axis

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same, if the charts have the animation option on, I think that is causing the redraw to be called multiple times